The DiffPrivLib version of Decision Tree is giving me the wrong accuracy
IBM specifically designed their differential privacy library, DiffPrivLib, to work exactly like scikitlearn for ease of use. The tutorials on their github site state that if using epsilon = infinity (and, presumably, the same random state) with DiffPrivLib you should get an identical model to the non-private version from scikitlearn. Ref: github.com/IBM/differential-privacy-library/blob/main/notebooks/…
I've confirmed that this works with Gaussian Naiive Bayes, but when using almost identical code frameworks with the Decision Tree Classifier, I'm getting radically different values. Has anyone else encountered this? Can you see what's wrong with my code?
This is the code to run a non differentially private Decision Tree using scikitlearn, this works fine. (Updated to use sklearn dataset for repeatability):
# Import necessary packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import diffprivlib as dp

# Load breast cancer dataset into a dataframe
dataset = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
data = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset.data, columns=dataset.feature_names)
data['target'] = dataset.target
    
# Split into test and training sets
X = data.drop(['target'], axis=1)
y = data['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

# Build a Decision Tree Classifier
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)

# Model training
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict Output
y_pred_dt = dt.predict(X_test)

# Output metrics
print(matthews_corrcoef(y_test, y_pred_dt))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_dt))

For now, my MCC and confusion matrix looks like this (almost perfect):
0.8170347321131809
[[40  4]
 [ 4 66]]

Now for the problem area. With epsilon set to infinity and using the same random state as above I 'should' be getting the same values and I'm not. Here is my code:
# Calculate the bounds to prevent a privacy warning with DP-RF
min_values = data.min().tolist()[:-1]
max_values = data.max().tolist()[:-1]
bounds = (min_values, max_values)

# Define the classes to prevent a privacy warning with DP-RF
classes = np.array([0, 1],)

# Build a Decision Tree Classifier
DPdt = dp.models.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42, epsilon=np.inf, bounds=bounds, classes=classes)

# Model training
DPdt.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict Output
y_pred_DPdt = DPdt.predict(X_test)

# Output metrics
print(matthews_corrcoef(y_test, y_pred_DPdt))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_DPdt))

And this is giving me dramatically different classification
0.2813017973520981
[[13 33]
 [ 5 63]]

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?
Update:
I have re-run the problem using DiffPrivLib's Random Forest and the sklearn breast cancer dataset. This has the same problem.
# Load the required packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import diffprivlib as dp
    
# Load breast cancer dataset into a dataframe
dataset = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
data = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset.data, columns=dataset.feature_names)
data['target'] = dataset.target

# Calculate the bounds to prevent a privacy warning with DP-RF
min_values = data.min().tolist()[:-1]
max_values = data.max().tolist()[:-1]
bounds = (min_values, max_values)

# Calculate the classes to prevent a privacy warning with DP-RF
classes = np.array([0, 1],)
    
# Split into test and training sets
X = data.drop(['target'], axis=1)
y = data['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
    
# Calculate the MCC for the non-DP version of RF
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_rf = rf.predict(X_test)
rf_MCC = matthews_corrcoef(y_test, y_pred_rf)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_rf))
print("MCC: ", rf_MCC)
    
# Build a Differentially Private Random Forest Classifier
epsilon = np.inf  # Example epsilon value for differential privacy
    
DPrf = dp.models.RandomForestClassifier(epsilon=epsilon, random_state=42, bounds=bounds, classes=classes)
DPrf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_DPrf = DPrf.predict(X_test)
y_pred_DPrf = y_pred_DPrf.astype(int)
DPinf_MCC = matthews_corrcoef(y_test, y_pred_DPrf)
    
# Output metrics
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_DPrf))
print("MCC: ", DPinf_MCC)

Repeated by iterating across a range of epsilon values and averaged over 30 runs and you get this:

The DP version of RF is converging at a dramatically lower accuracy than the standard sklearn version.

This would be better with a toy dataset that recreates the problem. Are you sure that (they claim that) the equivalence is supposed to hold for a decision tree too?

IBM originally only released a few ML models of which DT was not the first. I can't find much on DT so I can not say for certain. But it does seem intuitive that since it works for NB and it appears LR as well that it should also work for DT.

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but I also don't know much about this package. Maybe ask on their github page (as an a Issue)? (If you do, link to here from there and vice versa.)

I notice that the docstring for the decision tree says "This class implements the base differentially private decision tree classifier for the Random Forest classifier algorithm. Not meant to be used separately.", but surely if this fails for the tree it also fails for the random forest, which maybe isn't supposed to happen.

Updated to show the issue persists even with the diffprivlib version of random forest. Unless you can spot something dramatically wrong in my code @BenReiniger, I think this needs to go to the IBM git hub site as a bug of some kind.

https://github.com/IBM/differential-privacy-library/issues/93
